# How can I access a static variable from another method?

Tags: c++, variables, static

is it possible to access the variable `myVar` from `foo2()`?

```
struct A {
    void foo() {
        static int myVar;
    }

    void foo2() {
        // can I access A::foo::myVar from here ??
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Massimo

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: It is, returning a pointer/reference to it (as some C functions do) BUT you're in C++ then you should seriously consider if it shouldn't be changed to a private class field...

Answer (score 4):

You could return a reference to it from the function:

```
int& foo() {
    static int myVar;
    return myVar;
}

void foo2() {
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Note that it isn't clear from your question *why* you need to access this variable. There could well be better solutions for whatever problem it is you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

No, `myVar` is only a valid symbol within `foo()`. If you want to access it from other functions, promote it into the class, like this.

```
struct A {
    static int myVar;

    void foo() {
        A::myVar;
    }

    void foo2() {
        A::myVar;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not access `myVar` variable in another function.It will be better if you make `myVar` as struct data member.

```
struct A {
    static int myVar;

    void foo() {

    }

    void foo2() {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to local variables declared in the body of other methods. So the answer is no, put the variable global to the class and there you will have access